# Countdown Freeze using Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

I'm trying to create a countdown using Svelte. But somehow, the output is not dynamic, it does not change until I refresh the page, then the value would change. There's probably a logical error in my codes. is there any to begin with? or it's just svelte's compiler that has been bugging??
Thank you

```
    import { tweened } from 'svelte/motion';
    var expected = new Date("Feb 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    let distance = tweened(expected-now);

    setInterval(()=> {
        if ($distance > 0){
            $distance-=1;
        }
    },1000)
  $: days = Math.floor($distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  $: hours = Math.floor(($distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  $: minutes = Math.floor(($distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  $: seconds = Math.floor(($distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a logical issue with your code -- you are only subtracting 1 millisecond from `distance` every second instead of 1000 milliseconds (1 second).

If you update your code to subtract 1000 milliseconds at a time instead of 1, the countdown works as expected.

```
setInterval(()=> {
    if ($distance > 0){
        $distance -= 1000;
    }
}, 1000)
```